# How can I use pre-request script in salesforce?

Tags: rest-api, salesforcedx

I have a pre-request script and an endpoint which I can use to fetch access token in postman. How can I use the same script in Salesforce to get the access token?

Comment: Hi user51241, could you please edit your question to add more details about exactly what you are doing and include the code you're trying to use? I for one am not sure what a "pre-request script" is, or whether you're writing Apex or some other language, and in what context you are working.

Comment: Why are you using postman to fetch an access token? Can't you just do that with an `sfdx auth` request?